# FPGA vs CPU: what operations are impossible on a processor

Tags: fpga, microprocessors

In this presentation here:

http://opensource.zylin.com/workshop/fpga.pdf

on slide 12, titled "How do I know I need an FPGA?", one of the specified reasons is:

"Some operations are impossible in a microprocessor"

Is this metaphorically speaking for something like "it would be very long to do those operations on a processor", or simply there are some operations with are really impossible for a processor, but feasible on a FPGA.

If there are such operations, what are those?

Comment: If you really want to know what the author meant, you need to write them and ask.  Microprocessors are generally [Turing Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), and FPGAs have no special magic to assist in computing the uncomputable.  Some problems they can solve faster...that's all.

Comment: @HostileFork: Thanks. I have general knowledge about how FPGAs work, but this remark surprised me.

Comment: It's impossible timestamp an asynchronous external event with 50ps resolution using a processor, probably.

Comment: @Chiggs: Well, that could be an answer. If you post it as an answer and elaborate a bit, I will select it and consider the question answered.

Comment: It sounds a bit like like "some things a general-purpose CPU couldn't do in even approximately the same way as dedicated hardware," i.e., it's not close to native, and whatever you do to emulate the operation on a CPU isn't in some sense the same operation anymore. This at least used to be true of, say, 128-bit carry-less multiplication (then Intel added an instruction for it).

Answer (score 3):

There exist quite complete software simulators for FPGA designs, so any logic which can be configured into an FPGA can be implemented on a microprocessor.

However, the timing is very different, *especially* in simulation.

So if timing requirements are part of the definition of "operation", then some operations cannot be performed by the F/D/X processor, which are feasible for an FPGA.

In addition to implementation of logic, FPGAs also contain some analog-ish blocks.  For example, the I/O pads for differential digital signals can be used as analog comparators for [implementation of ADC and DAC blocks](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/Documents/WhitePapers/AG/CreatingAnADCUsingFPGAResources.PDF?document_id=36525).  PLLs are also commonly found in FPGAs.  As well as large numbers of I/O pins.  Microprocessors generally have none of these features (although microcontrollers may), so FPGA designs using them can't be duplicated on a processor.

Comment: You are right about the analogic part, but it is a bit unfair to compare a processor with an FPGA based in that only. Because, this way, one could say that even a dumb resistor or capacitor is better than a processor. I think the comparison only makes sense on the digital side. However, this is an answer that might be considered; thank you.